# VBoxClient error in BitDefender rescue CD

Tags: antivirus, virtualization

I'm afraid that I am targetted by hackers. To resolve this, I'm now trying the BitDefender rescue CD. When starting it, I get the following error notification:

> VBoxClient: VirtualBox kernel service isn't running.

The system does continue, however, I don't trust this since I don't know why VirtualBox is needed. I know VirtualBox is a program to make fake hardware for OS'es, in order to disable full control over the computer. I was already convinced I didn't have full control. Is this a proof I've been hacked?

Another issue is that BitDefender lists a lot of "Permission denied" errors in the status report, how would I resolve this? (I use Ubuntu 18 as OS.)

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for your question, however, I do not believe it to be the correct place to post; due to that I am flagging this post.

Comment: This question is specific to problems when running a commercial product. It looks like you need product support for this, so please contact the vendor.

Comment: `I know VirtualBox is a program to make fake hardware for OS'es, in order to disable full control over the computer. I was already convinced I didn't have full control. Is this a proof I've been hacked?` "Fake" isn't the right word, you mean "Virtualized", also, this has nothing to do with you being hacked. Bitdefender might have very good reasons like sandboxing to use virtualisation, which might interfere with Virtualbox. (Like for example Hyper-V installation causing VMWare to break because of CredentialGuard). On a final note, virtualization does not mean you don't have full control.